# Declaring sum globally

Tags: latex3, xparse

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\shcpoint}{ m }
 {
  \azetina_shcpoint:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtotal}{ }
 {
  \int_to_arabic:n { \g_azetina_totalpoints_int }
 }

\int_new:N \g_azetina_totalpoints_int
\box_new:N \l_azetina_points_box
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azetina_shcpoint:n #1
 {
  \int_gadd:Nn \g_azetina_totalpoints_int { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_azetina_points_box { (0 ~ \textit{points}) }
  \makebox[\box_wd:N \l_azetina_points_box][l]
   {
    (\textit{#1 ~ point\int_compare:nT { #1 > 1 } { s }})
   }
  \quad
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Total points: \printtotal

\shcpoint{1} X

\shcpoint{3} X

\shcpoint{1} X

Total points: \printtotal

\end{document}
```

In the example above, the total points are calculated correctly at the end but if I try to call the command before the declaration of the points, it prints zero.

What is the best way to redefine this so that the sum can be accessed anywhere in the document?

Note the solution was provided by @egreg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160089/10898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the total to the `.aux` file (so naturally you need to run the document at least twice to get the sum right).  I added a new counter, so you have one to print the sum, which will be wrong when you add/remove points until you rerun the document, and another that will keep track of the points during the document run.  At the end of the run they are compared and a warning is issued so you know you have to rerun LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\shcpoint}{ m }
 {
  \azetina_shcpoint:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtotal}{ }
 {
  \int_to_arabic:n { \g_azetina_totalpoints_int }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\shcsettotal}{ m }
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_azetina_totalpoints_int {#1}
 }

\int_new:N \g_azetina_totalpoints_int
\int_new:N \g__azetina_counttotal_int
\box_new:N \l_azetina_points_box
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azetina_shcpoint:n #1
 {
  \int_gadd:Nn \g__azetina_counttotal_int { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_azetina_points_box { (0 ~ \textit{points}) }
  \makebox[\box_wd:N \l_azetina_points_box][l]
   {
    (\textit{#1 ~ point\int_compare:nT { #1 > 1 } { s }})
   }
  \quad
}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument
  {
    \iow_now:Nx \@auxout
      {
        \shcsettotal { \int_use:N \g__azetina_counttotal_int }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnF \g__azetina_counttotal_int = \g_azetina_totalpoints_int
      {
        \msg_warning:nn { azetina } { rerun-points }
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { azetina } { rerun-points }
  {
    Point~count~differs.~Rerun~LaTeX~to~get~it~right.
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Total points: \printtotal

\shcpoint{1} X

\shcpoint{3} X

\shcpoint{1} X

Total points: \printtotal

\end{document}
```

After the first run you have

[image]

and a warning in the `.log`:

```
Package azetina Warning: Point count differs. Rerun LaTeX to get it right.
```

and after the second run, no warning and

[image]

Comment: This is the first time I see the use of the `.aux` file to save a value. Thanks

Comment: @azetina You're welcome! That's pretty much what the `.aux` is for.  It saves things across runs (for example when you define a `\label` after the `\ref`erence).

Comment: Thanks. You have inspired me. I should buy you a coffee.

Comment: @azetina Yay, coffee :)  If we meet someday, I'll remember this ;-)